# Sharepoint Search Relevance Results

Tags: search

Is it possible to set relevance on the search results?.

Right now one user wants to search in a specific site (this is working) and with the results mark one more to be more “relevant” to be display at the top of the results and also to have a count of how many times does this documents has been open (the count is for each user).

If this is possible out of the box, can you tell me in which version of SharePoint 2007, 2010 or 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the ranking criteria in Sharepoint 2010, but it seems like quite a bit of work. Have you taken a look at this post?

[SP2010 Search - Crawling websites, how to manipulate results ranking?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/sp2010-search-crawling-websites-how-to-manipulate-results-ranking)